# How can I upgrade PostgreSQL 9.3.10 to PostgreSQL 9.4.5 in Ubuntu?

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu, heroku

Hello and excuse my english.

I'm trying to pull a remote database with heroku, but it gives me this error:

```
pg_dump: server version: 9.4.5; pg_dump version: 9.3.10
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
pg_restore: [archiver] input file is too short (read 0, expected 5)
```

I'm guessing I just need to upgrade my current version 9.3.10 to server version 9.4.5, but is not clear to me how to do it.

PD: I don't mind losing the data of my current databases.

Comment: Why not 9.5.0?  There are a number of significant performance improvements with 9.5.  It's worth it.

Comment: The remote postgreSQL is 9.4.5, so I need that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found was to completely delete postgresql 9.3 and then installed postgresql 9.4